Adding a row to a table in Excel with Powershell formats it like the row above. I want default formatting
If I create an Excel table object with Powershell and use it to insert a row into the table like
$Table.ListRows.Add()

It formats the new row like the row above it. If the row above has been filled with grey, it will be filled with grey, for example. If I use the GUI and tab past the last column of the last row, it adds a new row, but it is formatted like the default for the table style in use (with banded rows, for example). How can I use Powershell to get that format applied? (color and text formatting)
I'm running Microsoft 365 Excel version 2405 (build 17628.20188) on Windows 10 22H2 with Powershell 7.4.4.

I cannot reproduce your symptom in in Excel version 16.0.17830.20138 / Office 2019. Please add details about your runtime environment to your question.

I figured it out. This will just clear any formatting that got added and leave the default formatting of the table.
$Table.ListRows[$NewRow.Index].range.ClearFormats()
